# How to divide a View into equal size of rows and column (cells) from xml in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, gridview

I am creating a Snakes and ladder game on android. For the board, I am using a background image. When that background is loaded, I get the height and width of this image, and according to it resize the tokens(player 1 and 2 token), and place them at appropriate position. For calculating position, I divide the height and width with number of rows and columns. For moving each token I am changing there x and y position appropriately in the OnDraw method.

This solution is working but this is not efficient and it have some problems like tokens move with different speeds on different resolution screens, and the code has also become complex.

So is there a way in which I can divide the View into given numbers of rows and columns and then move the tokens using animation class. Or any other efficient solution.

I have tried using GridView in xml but it doesn't divide the cells into equal size. Also in onCreate method I am not getting the Height and width of the background image.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry if question is not formated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this type of format, may be it will help you..
```

> ```
>   <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTop"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
> ```

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/browseButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>
```